How can I cleanly do a lookup of a value with a substring extracted from a hostname in bash?
the following bash regex will set the memory variable according to machine hostname name
we have in the lab many machines with different name as following small example
presto01
presto02

hadoop01
hadoop02

mngmnthadoop01
mngmnthadoop01
.
.
.

for example if hostname - is contain the presto name or mngmntpresto name , then following bash code will set the variable memory to 23G
hostname=$( hostname -s )

[[ $hostname =~ (^|^mngmnt)presto[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && memory=23G
        
[[ $hostname =~ (^|^mngmnt)hadoop[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && memory=12G
        
[[ $hostname =~ (^|^mngmnt)kafka[[:digit:]]+$ ]] && memory=10G
.
.
.
    

but as I know case in bash not support regular expressions
but doing my code as I explained isn't so elegant , and I am wondering  if we can do it better ?

there is non need of regex: case ${hostname#mngmnt} in *presto[]0-9]* ) memory=23G;;  *hadoop[0-9]* ) ...

what in case presto is with diff name as master-presto , then we need the regex

@Judy, *presto still matches master-presto as a glob rather than as a regex

You could use a case statement with extended globbing patterns:
shopt -s extglob
case $hostname in
    ?(mngmnt)presto+([[:digit:]]) ) memory=23G;;
    ?(mngmnt)hadoop+([[:digit:]]) ) memory=12G;;
    ?(mngmnt)kafka+([[:digit:]])  ) memory=10G;;
    *) printf 'ERROR: Unrecognized hostname: %s\n' "$hostname" >&2;;
esac


See the extglob section in glob - Greg's Wiki for an explanation of shopt -s extglob and extended globbing.


Use a capture group to extract the part of the hostname after mngmnt, then use that in a case statement.
$BASH_REMATCH is an array containing the matches for the capture groups.
if [[ $hostname =~ ^(mngmnt)?([[:alpha:]]+)[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
then
    case "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" in
        presto) memory=23G ;;
        hadoop) memory=12G ;;
        kafka) memory=10G ;;
        *) echo "Unrecognized hostname: $hostname"
    esac
else
    echo "Unrecognized hostname: $hostname"
fi

